# Displaying a dynamically generated field in a template - field nested in an object in an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm retrieving some data from the server, it's structured like this (just an example, my actual object has many many more fields):

```
objFromServer = {
  name: 'Penny',
  details: {
    city: 'Chicago'
  }
};
```

Now, to display this in the template, I have get translations for each field key. Because my actual object has so many fields and I want to iterate through them in the template (rather than create html containers for each field), I've created an object that maps the translation key to the field name in the object from the server:

```
  objMap = [
    { translationKey: 'userFirstName', field: 'name' },
    { translationKey: 'userCity', field: 'details.city' }
  ];
```

Now, in my template I'm doing this to display each field, only I can't figure out how to display the `objFromServer.details.city`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objMap">
  {{ item.translationKey | translate }}: {{ objFromServer[item.field] }}
</div>
```

Of course, for the top level field, `name`, the template is able to do `objFromServer[name]`, so that works fine. But then it'll also try to do `objFromServer[details.city]` -- which  doesn't actually work. I tried a number of things with the bracket notation to try to get this to work... like changing the `field` to `'[details][city]'` but no luck there.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvtjdb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Is what I'm trying to do possible to achieve just within the template, without first flattening `objFromServer`? If so, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to create a helper function or filter to parse the field and get the value back from the object? So you'd have something like: `{{ item.tramslationKey | tranlate }}: {{ objFromServer | byComplexKey(item.field) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, is to create a function that based from a key path (example: `'details.city'`), seperate each key and drill down the object until it reaches the desired key.

Try adding this function to your component or service class.

```
getMapValue(field: string) {
  const keys = field.split('.');
  let obj: any = this.objFromServer;
  keys.forEach(key => obj = obj[key]);

  return obj;
}
```

Then, in your template, invoke that function with the corresponding key path, like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objMap">
  {{ item.translationKey }}: {{ getMapValue(item.field) }}
</div>
```

Now, this works but creates a different problem, that function will be evaluated every time change detection is executed even though the object has not changed, therefore, a custom pipe would be the next logical step.

One possible example would be:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'objectKey',
  pure: true
})
export class ObjectKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(field: string, object): any {
    const keys = field.split('.');
    let obj: any = object;
    keys.forEach(key => obj = obj[key]);

    return obj;
  }

}
```

And its use:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objMap">
  {{ item.translationKey }}: {{ item.field | objectKey: objFromServer }}
</div>
```

Working example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvgx4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Wow, great solution. Thank you so much!